# How do I check the current cmd aliases?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I know how to set command prompt aliases (using the doskey command) from another stack overflow thread, but given a command prompt, how do I find out which aliases are already set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this command. It will return aliases that are already set.

```
doskey /MACROS:ALL
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the short answer but just type

```
$ alias
```

This command is available in Linux and cigwin / bash on Windows.

Comment: Well, the question _is_ tagged `bash-alias`...

Comment: @DavidPostill it's not clear if he's using bash on windows 10 or just a regular command prompt.  I took an assumption it was either cygwin or bash on windows 10.

Comment: Given that he using doskey and a command prompt I think we can assume the bash-alias tag is a mistake.

Comment: Indeed it was, so I removed it now.
I refer to windows' regular command prompt.